# How can i make sure the image quality is intact when i load a very large image in Qquickpainteditems custom class in Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt, qml

i have overrided the paint method of QQuickpainteditems and displaying an image :

```
QRectF bounds = boundingRect();
QImage scaled = m_image.scaledToHeight(m_image.height());
QPointF center = bounds.center() - scaled.rect().center();

QPointF topLeft = bounds.topLeft();

// Draw the image


 qreal scaleX = static_cast<qreal>(width()) / static_cast<qreal>(m_image.width());
 qreal scaleY = static_cast<qreal>(height()) / static_cast<qreal>(m_image.height());
 qreal scaleFactor = qMin(scaleX, scaleY);

QImage resizedImage = m_image.scaledToWidth(m_image.width() * scaleFactor , Qt::SmoothTransformation);

painter.drawImage(topLeft, resizedImage);
```

My original image is 5000 by 5000 pixels but when it is scaled down, i lose the image quality .
How can i make sure the image always fits my frame size and never lose the image quality when scaled down?

Comment: you should keep aspect ratio when scaling an QImage: e.g. image = image.scaled(width(), height(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio). Check [this](https://github.com/omrdk/qopenai/blob/master/example/src/InteractiveImage.cpp#L31) class for more information.